Efficient computation of $x^n \bmod g(x)$ in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$
Related to this question. I wish to compute $x^n \bmod g(x)$ in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ for some fixed and known upfront $g$. This problem pops up in computing the 'pure' CRC function of a bit sequence of an one followed by $n$ zeroes. Omitting a lot of unnecessary information, having a fast method to compute the coefficients of the resulting polynomial lets us very quickly compute CRC-32C checksums via instruction-level parallelism.
My best method to solve this is logarithmic in $n$ and uses a trick vaguely resembling repeated squaring, i.e. I compute $x^{2^n} \bmod g(x)$ in $n$ steps. I am somewhat skeptical of the existence of the closed form, as the period of the binary sequences formed by the resulting polynomial for increasing $n$ seems very high.
We know for a fact that $n < 2^{64}$, so any method requiring reasonable (computationally) amounts of tabulation is acceptable.

You can factor $g$ and use the Chinese remainder theorem to split $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/g(x)$ into factors. For example if $g$ is separable, it will split as product of finite fields $\mathbb{F}_q$. In each of those $x^n$ will be $q-1$-periodic.

Your current method is the standard one. Typically in CRC32 applications $g$ will be chosen such that the period of $x$ is $2^{32}-1$.

This is question more suitable for https://cs.stackexchange.com

If you want calculate the CRC of a weight one input, then square-and-multiply is your friend. If you calculate the CRC of a real message block, then you need to process all those thousands of bits anyway. I'm fairly sure that a device like a linear feedback shift register can be tweaked to calculate such a remainder. I would think the fastest hardware would be some dedicated piece like that (if you do a bit of homework, you should be able to parallelize that as well (split the data chunk into several blocks, and precompute starting points of the LFSRs for the chunks, and in the end XOR them
